# omap a letter differently depending on what is already typed

Tags: vim

I have a custom keyboard layout. And so I have the vim commands `h`, `j`, `k` and `l` bound to other letters, e.g. I have bound `j` to `e`, like so: `nmap e j`.

The problem with this is that in operator pending mode, I sometimes want `e` to mean `j`, and sometimes I want it to mean `e`. For example when I am pressing `de` I want it to mean `dj`, but when pressing `te` I want it to mean `te`.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

I could do `omap de dj` but that does not work if I want to delete more lines by typing `d3e`. If there was (I don't think so, or is there?) some way to match numbers, for example with #, then I could to something like `omap d#e d#j`. Or maybe there is some way to change the mappings depending on what I have already typed in operator pending mode.

Comment: why you are demanding so much? Why dont you map all those differing keys to vim standard keys ?

Comment: Peeyush, do you mean that I shouldn't remap hjkl? That would be totally uncomfortable.

Comment: What you are doing seems to be the exact opposite of Vim's philosophy. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should hardly consider doing this with `*noremap`, not `*map`.
2. `nnoremap e j` can’t possibly spoil `te`. Neither can `onoremap e j`: `t` is *not* an operator and it does not invoke operator-pending mode.
3. `omap de dj` has nothing to do with `de` pressed in *normal* mode, you should press `dde` to invoke *this* mapping. And `nnoremap e j` has nothing to do with changing meaning of `de`: you need `onoremap e j` here (operator-pending mode is invoked by the operator `d`, but operator must be typed in normal mode. Neither it is a part of invoked mode).
4. Remapping of basic movement keys is the perfect example of those rare cases when you need `noremap`, without leading `n`, `o`, `v` or something. Try doing

   ```
   noremap e j
   ```

   for all keys you want to remap, this should be sufficient.
5. Remapping does not happen at the start of the mode, so no need to do `onoremap 3e 3j`. `onoremap e j` will also enable doing `d3e`->`d3j`. And `noremap e j` is equivalent to

   ```
   nnoremap e j
   onoremap e j
   vnoremap e j
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that `t` does not invoke operator-pending mode. Some addon fooled me a while back, and since then I have not had any omappings. :p